# How do I stop dark mode from destroying my css

Tags: css

I have a website with css styling. When I view in certain browsers when dark mode is enabled the css is absolutely destroyed and the colours which have changed in my site look absolutely hideous. How can I prevent my css/colourschemes being changed because of dark mode?

When I opened my url via a link sent on whatsapp on my android device the default browser - Android's 'internet' application automatically restyles the CSS because I have dark mode active. If other users go to my page and have dark mode active I would prefer them to see the original styling not the dark mode edited version.

I found out that you can use this media query to set css for dark mode: `@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {`. I could duplicate my whole css file which is currently 3000 lines long with dark and light with the same code between the parentheses but this seems nonsensical. Is there any other methods which would work?

[image]

Comment: I don't understand, which browser changes colours of the website in dark mode? Please give a concrete example of css and browser (and browser setting) that reproduces your issue. It's usually the opposite, websites aren't responding to dark mode unless they specifically have the `prefers-color-scheme` media query.

Comment: When I opened my url via a link sent on whatsapp on my android device the default browser - Android's 'internet' application automatically restyles the CSS because I have dark mode active. If other users go to my page and have dark mode active I would prefer them to see the original styling not the dark mode edited version. @dirkgroten

Comment: A browser isn't supposed to do that! What browser is this exactly (what brand of phone)? The `prefers-color-scheme: dark` flag tells the website that the entire **OS** is set to dark mode and the user would prefer to see a dark site. When the user switches their OS to dark mode, your website should still be unchanged (light) if you don't have specific CSS for it.

Comment: @dirkgroten, some clients force dark mode updating styles according to their feel of perfection. E.g. OSX Mail.

Comment: @KoshVery I tried the media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) and (prefers-color-scheme: light) and it completely killed my css on a normal screen.

Comment: @nerdychick, could you please be so kind to add a [mcve] to your question?

Comment: @KoshVery then I'm not sure there's much you can do about it, which is to show why dark mode is the worse thing ever invented... Also note that OSX Mail does not change the styling of HTML mails, I'm looking at it right now, our HTML formatted email has a light background and Mail doesn't touch it.

Comment: @KoshVery I have added an image to show what I mean.

Comment: @nerdychick is the dark mode set in the browser or at the OS level? And is there a setting in the browser that you switched to force website content to be dark? Because in Chrome there is such a switch (fairly well hidden so the majority of users won't touch it) but it is my opinion that if users flip that switch, they accept that all the websites look terrible. Anyway, you should try duplicating your css within the `@media` dark, just to see if the browser does it (which I believe it won't).

Comment: Without a sample of your code, how do you expect us to help you? All we can do is ask more questions and guess more hypotheses all the while never solving your problem. Edit your question with more details please.

Comment: Why do you need to see my code, its basic css like h1 { color: black;} my question is how do i stop it from going to white in dark mode @pensum

Comment: Do you mean when you reverse your colors in your phone? If that's the case, you can't. It's not meant to be beautiful, it's meant to save your eyes from having your screen too bright when you are in the dark.

Comment: @nerdychick, *I tried the media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) and (prefers-color-scheme: light) and it completely killed my css on a normal screen*: please try `@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) or (prefers-color-scheme: light)`.

Comment: @nerdychick what exactly did you do to get this behavior? Please explain in detail which settings in your OS and in your browser you changed, tell us which browser this is ("Internet" isn't the answer, there should be a UserAgent). Again, browsers don't change the appearance of websites even in dark mode, unless the user explicitly forces it to do so via a hidden setting. Chrome, Safari, Edge, Firefox and Opera don't just change the colours of your website.

Comment: Hey I believe it's Samsung OS browser-related. Even without specific styling for dark mode the browser will dim the color of images, text, input fields, and so on. I'm actually looking for a way to negate this behavior haven't found anything so far, anyone?

Comment: Are you talking about the Samsung browser? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Internet

Comment: For what it's worth, the former image is lancing my eyes every time I scroll past it, while the latter image was actually comfortable to look at. I wish they left your text black, but I *wish* I had this kind of color dimming in every browser I use for images and image-like content in dark mode.

Answer (score 28):

As it turns out, Samsung Internet — the default web browser for a very large number of devices and the one featured in your screenshot — silently applies a filter that transforms colors on websites in a non-trivial way when the user enables `dark mode` on their device. See [this blog post](https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/samsung-internet-night-mode.html) for more information.

The gist of it is that, as of Samsung Internet version 13.0.1.64, **this filter is undetectable with javascript or CSS.**

The only thing you can do as a web developer is to warn users and urge them to switch to a better browser:

```html
 <script>
   if (navigator.userAgent.match(/samsung/i)) {
       alert("Your browser (Samsung Internet) may not show this website" + 
             "correctly. Please consider using a standards-compliant" + 
             "browser instead. \n\n" +
             "We recommend Firefox, Microsoft Edge, or Google Chrome.");
   }
</script>
```

Comment: Ew ew ew ew ew. And upvote for this answer.
I'm just starting to get deeper into web/html/css dev stuff and the only thing worse than browsers is <style="font-family:creepy-dripping-green-shit">email clients...

Comment: One year later and it didn't change. Spend one hour chrome-emulating dark mode and didn't understand why my phone didn't react to the CSS changes. This or I have to (sigh) use samsung-internet-night-mode-accessible colors.

Answer (score 19):

Had the same issue. Here's what I found.

I added this meta tag to the header tag:

```
<meta name="color-scheme" content="light only">
```

The meta tag above indicates that the color scheme is only supported by light mode.

Another option is the scheme preferred in light mode, but it supports dark mode as well:

```
<meta name="color-scheme" content="light dark">
```

Tested on Safari, Chrome, Samsung, Facebook in-app browser and Firefox.

Another method is to use CSS:

```
:root {
     color-scheme: light only;
}
```

The above indicates that the styling only uses the light version only.

Comment: From what I see this does not work to prevent the Samsung Browser to apply its weird color adjustments

Comment: I tried to use this, and it doesn't work. Tested on the latest version of Chrome (107.0.5304.107)

Comment: this itself didn't work for me but <meta name="color-scheme" content="dark only"> did

Comment: color-scheme: light only; this works for me on edge, chrome, firefox and can be used to target just specific elements, in my case brand logo

Answer (score 0):

If I understood, you want users to see the so-called light version even if their browser is set to prefer the dark one. What I’m going to suggest is far from being perfect… I mean, I wouldn’t do so, but I think *it should work*. Simply copy and paste the CSS you wrote under a `@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark)` query and manually change what doesn’t work there, without changing the code outside its brackets. Users should see the original, light version of your website no matter what they selected in their browser setting. TBH, I don’t know why you want to do this: the ideal approach IMHO would be to provide both a light and a dark theme with a default fallback.

Comment: Actually if you don't do anything, any normal browser (Chrome, Safari, Edge, Opera, Firefox) will show the light version. Only if you **want to have a dark theme** do you need to do something.

Comment: The thing is, if OP is seeing a different behavior, it's likely the browser is setup to do something wacky and won't respond to `@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark)` anyway.

Comment: What I understood from OP is that he has a theme which is not light, nor dark. He concerned about having it changed by users who selected a dark theme in their browsers: I called it light, but in fact is a default theme he want to be showed in every mode. Tell me if I’m wrong. What I suggested here is a caveats to overwrite the browsers’ default CSS for dark mode when not defined, but as I said I wouldn’t do so.

Comment: but even if you choose dark mode, browsers don't change **any** website unless the website has **explicit** CSS to **support** dark mode. So the fact that OP is observing a change is what's strange here, because that's not how a browser is supposed to work!

Comment: I know, but maybe some Android mods (he said the test browser was _Internet_ and not _Chrome_) now overwrites the sites’ styling. OxygenOS, e.g., now has a Zen mode which disables some services. What about a similiar behaviuor for other platforms?

Comment: Maybe that's the case, but then again, in such a browser I doubt the @media query for dark mode will work (because it's supposed to help websites **detect** dark mode and decide for themselves whether or not to honour it) and therefore I don't think there's anything OP can do.

Answer (score 0):

I did some testing and the solution I found is using the !important declaration after the property value that you want to have when browser darkmode is on.

Think about this though, if you are using browser darkmode and go on a website and it stays the same as the lightmode, how would you feel? Personally I get really pissed and leave immediately from a website like that. So I would actually recommend not changing the colors. Users want darkmode for a reason, probably because they don't want bright colourful things hurting their eyes. If they want to use browser darkmode, they understand what will happen to the colors of websites.

The only use case I can see for changing things would be if elements disappear because of darkmode.

That being said, if your elements are disappearing because of this darkmode, look into the root cause first. Understand why they are changing before slapping !important on everything. That is lazy and does not look good on you as a developer.

Comment: I have a site which already is dark, but since the new dark mode in Firefox, some colours are changed which breaks  the overall style. How do I get rid of those unexpected changes?

Answer (score 0):

With everyone's input, I found a way to fix the problem perfectly sin Chrome. (Tested with chrome 122.)

Just write the following script inside the head tag.

```
    <!-- avoiding chrome force dark mode -->
    <script>
      var isDarkMode = window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches;
      if(isDarkMode){
        document.write(`<meta name="color-scheme" content="dark Only"><\/meta>`);
      }
    </script>
```

`meta color-scheme dark Only` means its not changed any css by force dark mode. But in light mode, some backgrounds are force changed to black.
So, I checked light/dark mode and write it on dark mode only.

Unfortunately, I do not have a valid test environment for Samsung browser, so I am waiting for comments from those who do.

Answer (score -1):

Before You do all that, **please check** if you did not do the mistake, that I did -
We're talking here about forced dark theme on mobile, that **You think** your browser, most probably Chrome, is forcing on every website making it's background black and text white.

What I had was a manually set chrome flag for forcing dark mode.

Go to Chrome and type address `chrome://flags` then search for "dark"
You'll find "Force Dark Mode for Web Contents" flag. If it's not already - set if to "default".

Hope it saves some time anybody, I've wasted 1h over this.

Edit(23.03.2024): It can also be forced by operating system setting(Theme: Dark mode), more here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-color-scheme

Though of course, in this case it's definitely in your code.

Comment: For whoever voted this down: Please have the courtesy of saying why. This remark is pertinent even if it doesn't anser the question directly. Please indicate if it is wrong.

Comment: @Will59 Thanks. Over the past 3 years since this my original comment, I've seen few cases which happened to be exactly that. As addition I'll add an update about system dark mode!

Answer (score -1):

You will face this issue in Samsung internet browser only. if the user has enabled dark mode In "Samsung internet browser(mobile)", the browser automatically changes the css of website to suit to dark mode. no matter if you applied the same css you applied for light mode/default within `@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark){}`

So if you want to make your website look better in Samsung internet browser, you can detect the samsung browser using this javascript line `navigator.userAgent.match(/samsung/i)` and apply separate CSS class for Samsung browser.

Comment: Why was this voted down, can you please comment when something is wrong?